# How to set dynamic subdomain cross server or in DNS setting

Tags: google-app-engine, dynamic, dns, subdomain

1. I have www.did5.com point to google appengine server
2. I want to have anyname.did5.com point to www.did5.com/anyname
3. And the url in address bar still anyname.did5.com

I can't find the way to do by using dns setting (host records)

Can anyone do ?

Please help..

Answer (score 1):

Have the same wish, but had to do HTTP 301 redirect from my domain hosting to an appengine site. It works normally, but it's required to have a working hosting, but not only domain parking.
So please try to edit ".htaccess" file, which must be in the root of site hosting, with

```
Redirect 301 / http://anydomain.com/any
```

Comment: If we use redirect the url address will change from 
abc.did5.com to www.did5.com/abc right ?

Comment: Using redirect you do not just changing url-string in a browser you change requsted page server, so you can redirect to any web page in the Internet. So you can redirect from "abc.did5.com to www.did5.com/abc" this way. If you need redirecting rules like somesubdomains.did5.com to did5.com/somesubdomains then i think you need to create redirection for every subdomain separately, but using one host for .htaccess.

Comment: but i don't want url in format www.did5.com/abc , I want abc.did5.com

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, App Engine doesn't currently support 'wildcard' CNAMEs. You have to specifically CNAME each domain that you want to use and configure it in the control panel. The only way to do what you want, currently, would be to host your own reverse proxy.