# Wildcard domain with federated type application on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I have used [Steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695812/programatically-setting-subdomain-on-google-app-engine/14709839#14709839) to make wildcard sub-domain to work on Google app engine, Godaddy and amazon route. Its working nicely for application with the authentication type (found in application setting in appengine dashboard) is Google Accounts API.

But, when I change application authentication type as federated account, it stops supporting wildcard sub-domain. Any idea to make it work with federated type application.

As always your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue found out was not related to application authentication type. But, there was problem with app.yaml file.